# Why do I have a "Portal 2" inventory?

Tags: steam

I don't have Portal 2, yet for some reason, Steam has decided to give me a "Portal 2" inventory.

It happened right about the time the Steam Gift Pile stuff kicked off.  I went to check my inventory, and I noticed that I have a new, empty, "Portal 2" tab.

Why?

Comment: IIRC it was included along with tf2 and spiral knights when the whole trade/inventory thing was implemented. I'm not sure what portal 2 items are available aside from the hats for Atlas and Peabody.

Comment: I've had a TF2 inventory for a while without the Portal 2 inventory.  IIRC, I *did* start playing Spiral Knights about the same time the Portal 2 inventory appeared, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you start Portal 2 (if you have it) there's a "Robot Enrichment" option at the bottom that is a link to an in-game item store. The items allow you to customize bots for co-op with paint jobs, gestures, and since Valve loves hats you can also get hats.

You can also get other items when you earn achievements, but most of those seem locked to trading.

So if you buy items in the Portal 2 in-game store or if any of the achievement items are tradeable, you can trade them with other people for anything they might have in any of the Steam inventories (TF2, Steam, Portal 2, Spiral Knights, etc).

I'm fairly certain they added the Portal 2 tab to inventories over the 2012 Holiday Sale when they added the promotional items, and that everyone got this tab regardless of whether they owned the game or not. (Maybe to try to sell more Portal 2, but it's never clear with Valve.)

Comment: Yes.  I get that.  Hence my first line: "I don't have Portal 2".  *I have never opened Portal 2.  I don't even own it.*

Comment: Right, so you don't have any Portal 2 items. Pretty sure everyone has the tabs for Portal 2, TF2 and Valve no matter what since they're all Valve properties.

Comment: Then why didn't I have a Portal 2 tab a month ago?

Comment: I believe they added it over the holidays when they added the promotional items. That's when it appeared for many people.

Comment: If I had to guess, it might have been possible to get Portal 2 promo items (like the hats in TF2), so it was enabled for everyone.

Comment: @InsidiousForce If you edit your answer to reflect your comments, I think it'd get it accepted. As it stands currently, your comments answer the question *slightly* more than your answer.